# Use Object Mode and Edit Mode in the 3D View

Tags: 3d-view

Is there a way in Blender to use a windowed 3D View with Object Mode and one with Edit Mode? Currently I can multiply the 3D View and use 2 windows, however they both switch whenever choose either Object Mode or Edit Mode. I would like to have just one window open in Object Mode and one in Edit Mode. 
How can I achieve this?

Thanks for reply

Comment: I asked the same question before. It appears currently there is no way to do this. http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66693/two-3d-view-windows-one-in-edit-mode-one-in-object-mode

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't currently. If you create two 3D Views, they will still be linked. When you enter into Edit Mode in one of them, the other one wil also.

Multiple 3D Views are mainly used for viewing diffirent angles at the same time.

Comment: Thanks! Let's hope the developers will add this feature in a future release.